# Change property type on the fly using Knockout mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, mapping, knockout-mapping-plugin

I need to use knockout mapping plugin to dynamically update an object with ajax json data. But the property type changes. For example, I receive json data like:

{"type" : "A", "output" : "This is A" }

or

{"type" : "B", "output" : {"Name" : "B"}}

or

{"type" : "C", "output" : ["C1", "C2", "c3"]}

I have different view templates in front end to present my model according to the type. But question is ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModle) is not working since output type is not fixed. How I can mapping it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple javascript objects representing each type.
You can feed a custom mapping to the plugin in which you can control the way an object is created (and also which type of object is created.

Something like this:

```
var mapping = {
create: function(json) {
    if(json.data.Type == 'A'){
        return new YourTypeA();

     }  
     //same for your other types
 }
}

var data = '[{ "Type": "A", "Titel": "Title1", "Description": "Description 1" }, { "Type": "B", "Titel": "Title 2", "Description": "Description 2" }, { "Type": "C", "Titel": "Title     3", "Description": "Description 3"}]';
    ko.mapping.fromJS(eval(data), mapping, viewModel);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, what you suggest works. But I have like twenty different types. Doing this manually is painful. While updating data, can I do something to delete the "output" property and let knockout auto mapping it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Just put items in a array, then mapping will be good.

```
data = [{"type" : "A", "output" : "This is A" }]
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModle)
data = [{"type" : "B", "output" : {"Name" : "B"}}]
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModle)
```